# Build a Form with 2 dropdown options that load a specific PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, get

I understand that is might be something that is already answered and I apologize if it is, I could not find it.

What I need to do is build a simple form that has two options, they will be dropdown options. Dropdown A and Dropdown B then a Submit button. This part I understand in HTML, although it may be easier in php or javascript.

Then I need it to take the two options and create a "if/then" statement that loads a specific pdf that matches the two options selected.

Example.
If someone selects Option 1 from Dropdown A and Option 2 From Dropdown B then it loads 12.pdf
If someone selects Option 5 from Dropdown A and Option 3 From Dropdown B then it loads 53.pdf
If someone selects Option 2 from Dropdown A and Option 1 From Dropdown B then it loads 21.pdf

and so on...

Thank you for any help.

**ADDITION** Here is my current HTML Form Script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<h1> Get Directions</h1>
<form action="results.html" method="get" name="directions" target="_new">

<select name="start" size="1">
<option value="north">North Tower Entrance</option>
  <option value="south">South Tower Entrance</option>
  <option value="moba">MOB A Entrance</option></select>
  
  ----->

<select name="end" size="1">
<option value="onco">Oncology</option>
  <option value="radio">Radiology</option>
  <option value="pulm">Pulmanary</option></select>
<br /><br />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at this code I need it to call on a specific pdf that will represent the combination of options. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use dropdown? i think it may be easier by input text boxes

Comment: This is absolutely no problem: You make your form, html based and have it submit the values of the selects to a server side script. That script decides which file to hand out based on the values the form submitted. The script can be coded in any language the server supports. Inside the script you use a catalog or nested switch statements to decide which file to offer. That's all. You do _not_ want to code this logic on the client side. Because 1. there is no reason for this and 2. that might open security issues.

Comment: The coding the actual action commands on the server side is where I am falling short, not quite understanding the steps for this. I have added the form script I am attempting to use for a better understanding, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFileName(select1Id, select2Id) {
    var sel1 = document.getElementById(select1Id);
    var sel1Index = sel1.selectedIndex;
    var sel2 = document.getElementById(select2Id);
    var sel2Index = sel2.selectedIndex;
    if((sel2Index + sel1Index) === 0) {
        return "";
    }
     return sel1Index.toString() + sel2Index.toString() + '.pdf';
}
```

You can pass the unique ID of your combo boxes to the above function and it will provide you the corresponding pdf file name. It will return empty if the name is 0

You can invoke the above function from your button click event handler, get the file name and load it in the web page.

- I haven't done the validations, which you can add

Hope this helps

Comment: This is great, my next question is where do I place this function? Also I added the script I am trying to work for the form action, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any javascript to make this happen, as arkascha mentioned. You can do this all server side.

You need (1) HTML document with form, (1) PHP script to process the selections and serve the appropriate result link.

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses, the php part is what I am having issues with. I have the form filled out in the HTML and it works well. The action is <form action="results.html" method="get" name="directions" target="_new">.

but do I need to set the form action to a php file, and understanding the code for the call is what I am missing. Thanks.